# ffmpeg copy file while recording

Tags: android, ffmpeg, streaming, record, mp4

I am developing an Android app that records and live streams videos through the mobile camera.
Right now, I am toggling between both of them. I want to record and stream at the same time.

While the file is being recorded, is not possible to stream using ffmpeg, because the MOV ATOM from the MP4 file information is not inserted in the file yet (it goes in the end).

Is there any way for the ffmpeg to:

1. read the file successfully while it it being recorded;
2. listen to every change in the file, so it stream the new bytes of
   information;
3. in case I go for another solution, like copying the streaming bytes to a file, can I correct the file via ffmepg to correct any missing headers?

**Edit:**

I decided to try a different approach by accessing the camera directly via command line using ffmepg. If it works, I can record the video and stream at the same time. I started trying the [FFMPEG library](https://github.com/hiteshsondhi88/ffmpeg-android-java) for android: with the following code inside a MainActivity:

```
    final FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {}

            @Override
            public void onFailure() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {}

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {}
        });
    } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
        // Handle if FFmpeg is not supported by device
        Log.e("FFMEPG","error", e);
    }


    try {
        // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
        ffmpeg.execute(" -y -f video4linux2 -s 320x240  -r 25 -i /dev/video0 /testing.mp4", new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.d("FFMEPG","start");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {
                Log.d("FFMEPG",message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                Log.e("FFMEPG",message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                Log.d("FFMEPG",message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.d("FFMEPG","finish");
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
        Log.e("FFMEPG","error", e);
    }

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ffmpeg.killRunningProcesses();
        }
    }, 10000);
```

And also giving the necessary permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

I am just trying to record a simple 10 seconds mp4 file from the camera, but I am getting the following error:

```
    03-05 12:52:29.391  22004-22004/test.testcameraffmpeg E/FFMEPG﹕ WARNING: linker: /data/data/test.testcameraffmpeg/files/ffmpeg has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
        ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
        built on Oct  7 2014 15:08:46 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
        configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a-neon --extra-cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
        libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
        libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
        libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
        libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
        libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
        libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
        libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
        libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
        [video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x424bad30] Cannot open video device /dev/video0: Permission denied
        /dev/video0: Permission denied
```

Do I have to be root  to access the camera? Did anybody try this approach?

Comment: How you want to stream, any protocol like RTSP?

Comment: Yes. I am using RTMP via a library called [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming)

Comment: Hi @BrunoSiqueira, we are having similar problems, did you manage to get it running in the end? Thanks!

Comment: I have not, @vektor. I listed all my similar attempts in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012335/android-recording-and-streaming-at-the-same-time)

Comment: still no progress? I am also looking for solution @BrunoSiqueira

Comment: No progress yet, @Manny264...

Comment: you have got any solution?

Comment: @RaviVGHL no solution yet. We are creating our own solution instead

Comment: It's too late but, I have successfully did recorded and stream camera video using FFMpegFrameRecorder.